# Looking for a neat SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Could somebody give me a piece of advice is it possible to shorten this line:

```
and docs.Filename not like '%^ABC.%' 
and docs.Filename not like 'Element%' 
and docs.Filename not like 'Sheet%' 
and docs.Filename not like '%^Copy%'
```

to something like this:

```
and docs.Filename not like ('%^ABC.%' OR 'Element%' OR 'Sheet%' OR '%^Copy%')
```

Now I have a problem with SQL Server 2014 Management Studio; it tells me this is the wrong syntax of 'OR'.

Comment: Why do you want to shorten the original line? There is also the possibility to split the line in some parts using CRLF.

Comment: No, there's no way to write it shorter.

Comment: When using LIKE, you need to write it the way you've done. In other SQL dialects, you could perhaps use regular expressions if you particularly want to avoid the repetition, but regular expressions aren't yet available in SQL Server. It's fine as is.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Not shorter for these items, but we can reduce repetition and therefore make it shorter for the general case of _n_ items.

Comment: @joel which would only make sense when the list is long. So long, in fact, that the entire thing might benefit from using an actual table... But yes, I agree.

Comment: First of all, I don't know how to answer specific comments. So I will try to answer all of them. In the original code line, I think the type "docs.Filename not like" is annoying and hard to understand especially in case I'll add some new rules. If it has one smart line for checking filename, for me it easy to read and correct in the future.
Next question what is CRLF? =).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be slightly *longer* for just these few values, but it scales better as you add more and puts the matched values closer together with less repetition.The key is putting the items in a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This also sets you up to easily convert to an actual table later on.

```sql
SELECT docs.*
FROM docs
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES 
       ('%^ABC.%'), ('Element%'), ('Sheet%'), ('%^Copy%')
    ) matcher(val)
    WHERE docs.Filename LIKE matcher.val
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

[De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) says you can rewrite it as:

```
and not ( docs.Filename like '%^ABC.%' or docs.Filename like 'Element%' or
  docs.Filename like 'Sheet%' or docs.Filename like '%^Copy%' )
```

That isn't a significant change unless you're playing [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).